# Translation/understanding お世話になっている場所

Tags: translation

Context: Manga shenanigans. Some normal people were taken to another world and shown magic there and brought back. Now back on Earth one of them is commenting on how she still hasn't completelly accepted what happened there subjectively. Then she says the following line.

> 実際に「凄いところ」やあちらの世界
>
> お世話になっている場所を見せて頂いたので

The line split is like that in manga so I'm assuming there is a comma missing there. But that's a bit besides the point.

The first line basically says:

> Actually "amazing thing (probably reffering to magic)" and that world/universe

the second line is a problem. 場所を見せて頂いた is fine. She is just saying that she (they) were allowed to see that place.

The problem is this bit **お世話になっている場所**. Now I know that "お世話になっている" means basically to feel gratefull for or have obligation to someone who helped you. **But how does it describe a place here?** The only thing I'd guess is that it is the person speaking saying she is gratefull for being able to see that place and magic and like in it.

Additional context: The next line is:

> 受け止めるしかないところではあるんですが

So I think the entire thing is probably something like:

> But given that we were able to actually see that “amazing thing” and that world, which we are grateful for, I have no choice but to accept that that thing (magic) is real, but…

So any help here?

**PS: Additional additional context:**

Yes, the background image of the text shows the daughter of the person speaking training to use magic at that place with her parents (one of them is the speaker) who are muggles watching. So I guess お世話になっている場所 in this context means place where assistance (in training) is received?

*bump*

Comment: お世話になっている場所 just means "the place where (someone) is taken care of / looked after". I believe you don't need a grammatical explanation. But we need a bigger context to explain what this 世話 actually refers to. Since it's in the progressive form, perhaps she is talking about a third person (her son, her friend, ...) who is currently receiving some assistance/training/protection from someone else.

Comment: @naruto additional context added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

お世話になっている場所 just means "the place where (someone) is taken care of / looked after". Judging from the context OP provided, this お世話になっている場所 seems to refer to the training site where her daughter is learning how to use magic. お世話になっている suggests her mother (speaker) is thankful about how her daughter is treated there.